# Erase successful, but not automatically formatting. Can't determine partition type - Jelly bean 4.1.2 with Nexus S

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-nexus-s, fastboot

While I ran the command - `fastboot flashall -w` I got the following error -

```
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: I9020XXLC2
Baseband Version.....: I9020XXKI1
Serial Number........: 3334E1630CFF00EC
--------------------------------------------
checking product...
OKAY [  0.001s]
sending 'boot' (3964 KB)...

OKAY [  0.693s]
writing 'boot'...
OKAY [  0.603s]
sending 'recovery' (4308 KB)...
OKAY [  0.541s]
writing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  0.652s]
sending 'system' (173123 KB)...
OKAY [ 22.336s]
writing 'system'...
OKAY [ 24.196s]
erasing 'userdata'...
OKAY [  0.243s]
formatting 'userdata' partition...
Erase successful, but not automatically formatting.
Can't determine partition type.
OKAY [  0.001s]
erasing 'cache'...
OKAY [  1.684s]
formatting 'cache' partition...
Erase successful, but not automatically formatting.
Can't determine partition type.
OKAY [  0.001s]
rebooting...

finished. total time: 50.956s
```

I'm trying the build Android jelly bean 4.1.2 in Nexus S phone.

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my Nexus 4 after flashing the factory images

What fixed it for me was going into [stock] recovery and selecting clear cache and doing a factory wipe, that seemed to fix the partition sizes

Oh also check to see that you have the latest bootloader on the device too, check out https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images for the most recent factory images

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. I'm little confused. I was actually following the instruction from here - http://source.android.com/source/building.html and here - http://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html. So I'm not sure where actually I should keep the latest bootloader in my phone.

Comment: Has all the data on your phone been wiped? I'm assuming yes but if its not I'd make a backup then flash the factory images and try again

Comment: Yes :( it wiped everything :(

Comment: Ok then flash the factory images I'd say, you'll get the most recent bootloader then. Use the link I poseted in my answer to find your device, if you are on windows then yo will need to either 1. extract the tar out into where your copy of factboot is or better [and what i do] just drop factboot into the folder that has the flash-all.bat in it. This will put your phone back to it's factory settings

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the partitions are on ext4. Maybe there is an option on fastboot (I never used it) where you can specify the patition type. That might solve it.